# Unable to fetch values from JSON returned from PHP API in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

The format I am getting from server is this

```
Object {
  "1": Object {
    "id": "EMP1_ID",
    "name": "EMP1",
  },
  "2": Object {
    "id": "EMP2_ID",
    "name": "EMP2",
  },
  "3": Object {
    "id": "EMP3_ID",
    "name": "EMP3",
  }
}
```

How can I get `id` and `name` in Javascript and store in an array?

This is what I am doing in PHP file

```
$arr = array();
$query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){
     $arr[$i] = array(  
          "id"=> $row[id],
          "name"=> $row[name]
       );
     $i=$i+1;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: This does not seem to be regular JSON. So, you need a parser of this specific format.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP pasted the result from `console.log()`.

Comment: @Rajat which entry? And why as an array?

Comment: I have updated the question. @RoboRobok

Comment: Not sure if that's what you meant, but please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.values`

```js
const obj = {
  "1": {
    id: "EMP1_ID",
    name: "EMP1"
  },
  "2": {
    id: "EMP2_ID",
    name: "EMP2"
  }
}

Object.values(obj) // [{id: "EMP1_ID", name: "EMP1"}, {id: "EMP2_ID", name: "EMP2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `json_encode()` to convert value to an array, your array needs to be properly indexed from 0 to n-1: `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]`. Associative array is PHP's thing. Try this:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){
     $arr[] = [  
          "id"=> $row['id'],
          "name"=> $row['name']
     ];
}
```

Notice how I just push to the `$arr` with `$arr[]` instead of using any explicit index.

Comment: This is not working, instead of getting index, I am getting Objects inside an Array.

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what you wanted. JS doesn't have associative arrays. PHP's `['a' => 1]` is `{a: 1}` in JavaScript.

Comment: I want to access values of Objects. Anyways, other solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, because `Object.values()` in this case does exactly the same thing as my PHP, except my answer cleaned your server-side output.

Answer (score 0):

@Robo Robok is right, your php code should look like this:

**EDIT:**

You should let the server do the hard job, and get the results already parsed.

```php
$arr = array();
// $query = "SELECT id,name FROM table";
$query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// where $row has id and name keys only (a little optimization)

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result))
     $arr[] = $row;

echo json_encode($arr);
```